# Components of a Vector in Spherical System

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, coordinate-systems

Let us consider the spherical system with unit vectors $ r,\theta ,\phi $

Consider a vector $\vec { a } = { a }_{ r }\hat { r } +{ a }_{ \theta  }\hat { \theta  } +{ a }_{ \phi  }\hat { \phi  } $

$\vec { a } $  is a vector is space with some arbitrary direction.

Since vectors can be translated,   $\vec { a } $  on translation to the origin will make all components other than those in $\hat{r}$  to be null. This would entirely change the original vector.

For a short example, a tangent to the circle  lies along $ \hat {\theta}$ . On translating this to the origin, the vector becomes radial along $\hat{r}$

What is wrong here?

Comment: It would change the components because the basis vectors depend on position, but it wouldn't change the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$, and $\hat{\phi}$ are position dependent, so you cannot simply translate the vector $a$ and keep the components $a_{r}$, $a_{\theta}$ and $a_{\phi}$ constant.  In fact, at the origin, these unit vectors are not defined.